# How can I allow near edge building in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to reroute a river and build dolomite block walls to get it look acceptable, but there are three tiles where I cannot build no matter what.
They shouldn't even be blocked since they are next to an edge wall.
As the perfectionist I am I'm trying to allow building on these specific tiles 
but I don't see any way to change the setting of edge tile building. Any idea how to solve this problem?

I'm using Dwarf Fortress 0.40.24 to play.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to build on the edge of the embark location?

Comment: Assuming you do mean the edge of the map. You can't build walls up to the edge. Nor can you dig on the edge (though you can dig fortifications). I am given to understand that you can build bridges up to the edge of the map. If this is three tiles next to some random interior wall, there was some sort of bug about unbuilt walls causing pathing issues for contruction. To work around that you need to remove the specifications for building anything not yet built in the area and then build things individually out from the least accessible area. Wait for each bit to finish before starting the next.

Answer (score 2):

The game tries to prevent you from building all the way to the edge of any map you embark on, probably to prevent your blocking of caravans, new immigrants, and goblin invasions.

The restrictions it puts on building close to the edge have limitations that other DF players have discovered:

1) You can build walls 5 tiles from the edge.

2) you can build fortifications 4 tiles from the edge.

3) you can channel 2 tiles from the edge.

4) you can build floors all the way to the edge.

5) You can build a drawbridge and then lower/extend it all the way to the edge.

If you want to create a drain for your river, you have two choices; find a way to empty the river over the edge of your map or channel it to some aquifer tiles, which can absorb any amount of water.

One way to empty water over the edge of the map is to dig down at the map edge and attempt to find one of the cavern layers under that point. If the cavern connects to the map edge, any water dumped down that hole will flow out of the map through the cavern.